# Optimizing multiple DB queries into one in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have the "incident" and "productData" objects below in my Node (app.js) file. I am looping through and making three DB calls if the product_id matches.

```
const incident = {
      primary_product_type: 'T',
      product_id: 29,
      components: 
       [ { component_id: 2,
           name: 'wheel',
           is_public: false,
           is_vehicle: false,
           is_equipment: false,
           is_tire: false,
           is_child_seat: false,
           is_active: false,
           is_deleted: false},
         { component_id: 3,
           name: 'brake',
           is_public: false,
           is_vehicle: false,
           is_equipment: false,
           is_tire: false,
           is_child_seat: false,
           is_active: false,
           is_deleted: false } ]
      }

const productData = { tires: [{
        tire_id: 1,
        product_id: 29, 
        complaint_id: 1,
        failure_type_cd: 'BST',
        failure_location_cd: 'PSR',
        original_equipment_cd: 'REPL',
        repair_type_cd: 'RSW',
        repair_location_cd: 'BE',
      },
      {
        tire_id: 2,
        product_id: 2,
        complaint_id: 1,
        failure_type_cd: 'BST',
        failure_location_cd: 'PSR',
        original_equipment_cd: 'REPL',
        repair_type_cd: 'RSW',
        repair_location_cd: 'BE'
      }]};
```

Here I loop and make three different calls by passing the type of code.

```
for (const x of productData.tires) {
          if (x.product_id === incident.product_id) {
            const getTireOeDescription = await productsDB.getProductDescriptionByCode(context, x.original_equipment_cd);
            const getTireFlDescription = await productsDB.getProductDescriptionByCode(context, x.failure_location_cd);
            const getTireFtDescription = await productsDB.getProductDescriptionByCode(context, x.failure_type_cd);
          }
        }
```

In the productDB file, I have a simple postgres sql to get description based on code passed a parameter.

```
const descriptionByCodeSql = ` 
  SELECT
description
  FROM ivoq.product_codes
  WHERE code = $1 and
    is_deleted != true`;

const getProductDescriptionByCode = async (context, code) =>
  db.selectOne(context.dbClient, descriptionByCodeSql, [code]);
```

The problem here is it will call it 3 times. I am trying trying to find a way to just call this sql exactly once.

Comment: What is `db`, what library are you using?

Comment: We use lodash. db is just a const used to require a file which has:                       const selectOne = async (db, sql, params = []) => _.first(await select(db, sql, params));

Comment: OK, then what is `select`? In any case, you should use `WHERE code = ANY($1)` and pass an array of ids, then match them to your three references.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`

```
const descriptionByCodeSql = ` 
  SELECT code, description
  FROM ivoq.product_codes
  WHERE code IN ($1, $2, $3) and
  is_deleted != true`;

const getProductDescriptionByCode = async (context, codes) =>
  db.select(context.dbClient, descriptionByCodeSql, codes);
```

Comment: This is what I initially tried, but the problem here will be how will we pass ($1, $2, $3)? 'codes' cannot be  of this format: (), if we make it an array and send, it'll be an incorrect sql syntax.

Comment: @KS You don't send multiple parameters as arrays? What ORM are you using?

Comment: @KS Also, your example uses an array `[code]`. Isn't it intended to carry one or more items?